# Web Api 2 Stateless with Users

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, stateless

I believe I understand the basics of sessionless/stateless REST but I am having problems with implementation in Asp.Net Web Api 2 because I haven't used it before. I have set up ApiControllers that use a custom System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute like this.

```
public class ApiAuthorizeAttribute : System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
            if (actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization != null)
            {
                //Set identity??
                return;
            }
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    }
}
```

I have a database that contains users and I need to use them for getting privileges to get/post/put/delete things but dont want to use a session. I have never worked with the asp.net Identity so I am not familiar with its features and capabilities.

My idea for implementation is to use user credentials or api secret signing to authenticate and get privileges for a user for every request. The question is, by using a AuthorizeAttribute or something similar, how do i give the controller(s) during that one request the user information if their credentials were correct?

UPDATE:
Is using this.User (ApiController.User) session based or can it be used for that single request. If so, how does one set it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that using IPrincipal and setting HttpContext.Current.User will allow the ApiControllers to access that user through using

```
this.User
```

with web api not having access to the session

```
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
        if (actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization != null)
        {
            //Check user credentials/token here
            //Get internal user

            IPrincipal principal = new MyOwnCustomPrincipal(internalUser);
            HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
            return;
        }
        actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use HttpContext.Items to hold user data for current requests.
After setting identity based on Auth header , you can have

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["userdata"]=userDataObject,
```

Another approach would be write your own action filter for authentication (but take utmost care)and pass data to controller.

```
public class MyAuthAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
       //do authorization here     

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        // Create object parameter.
        filterContext.ActionParameters["userdata"] = new User("John", "Smith");

    }
}
```

then in controller

```
[MyAuthAttribute]
ActionResult SomeAction(User userdata) //this will have user data
{

}
```

Comment: This seems a little extreme for putting in every single route for a restapi. When in a action in a Web Api controller, is 'this.User' based on a session or can that be set and used for that request

Comment: You can also opt for the CustomPrincipal approach , wrap user data in the principal.